# Angular Routing child routes

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, routes

I have pretty weird question about routing. That's my code so far:

`app.component.html`

`<router-outlet></router-outlet>`

Main routing module

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: "", component: LogOnComponent },
  { path: "groups",  loadChildren: () => import ('./groups/groups.module').then(m => m.GroupsModule), canActivate: [AuthGuard]},
];
```

Child routing in Groups.module

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: MenuComponent, children: [
      { path: '', component: GroupsComponent, outlet: 'start-outlet' },
      { path: 'permissions', component: PermissionsComponent, outlet: 'start-outlet' }
    ]
  }, 
];
```

And Menu.component has a line with child routing

`<router-outlet name="start-outlet"></router-outlet>`

And in Groups.component i want to redirect user to groups/permission like said in groups routing.

`<a [routerLink]="['permissions']" [state]="{ groupId: content.data.groupId }">link</a>`

The problem is redirection doesn't work. Angular said that he can't find this route

`ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'groups/permissions' Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'groups/permissions'`

What am I doing wrong ? Tried different placement of `permissions` but none seems to work. Any ideas of my mistakes ?

Comment: Can you try removing the "{ path: '', component: GroupsComponent, outlet: 'start-outlet' }," (i.e. so  that 'permissions' is the only child route) and re-try? I think the issue might be with two subsequent routes having no path. If  that's the case I'll write further explanation.

Comment: I hope you have registered the for root and for child routes correctly, it would be great if you can share your code on or similar example on the stackblitz.

Comment: After deleting this line GroupsComponent is not showing at path it was visible before and groups/permissions still has an error.

Answer (score 0):

I created a StackBlitz code sample. Here it is :
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-fxcqoy?file=src/app/menu/menu/menu.component.html